# how to analyze these type of time series data

Tags: regression, time-series, paired-data

my data consist of 35 measurements done at two different times (see plot below). I was wondering if a regression model could be created based not on the individual points (time 1 and time 2 treated as separate observations), but rather using the pairs of data (forgive the choice of words here). If you look at the plot, you can see that a nonlinear model could be created, the question is - can it somehow use the data pairs? Is there any modelling technique that allows this?

[image]

Comment: You would ask yourself why there were two measurements done in the first place.  What you can do is attempt to predict the second measurement at any given time after the first measurement, given the first measurement and the time of first measurement.